# Como colocar um formulário na view _Layout?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Estou tentando fazer um site com suporte a duas linguás.

Primeiro teste que fiz foi colocar esse código dentro de uma `view` comum, a `index` do meu controle `Home`.

Funcionou perfeitamente.

Quando eu coloco o mesmo código em uma `partial view` e chamo ele na view `_layout` ele não funciona. Alguém pode me dizer o que estou fazendo de errado?

Abaixo é o código como está na `partial view`, o que não funciona é o submit do form.

```
@{
    var culture = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name.ToLowerInvariant();
}

@helper selected(string c, string culture)
{
if (c == culture)
{
        @:checked="checked"
        }
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("SetCulture", "Home"))
{
    <fieldset>
        <legend></legend>
        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
                <label for="en-us">
                    <input name="culture" id="en-us" value="en-us" type="radio" @selected("en-us", culture) /> English <img src="http://st.xptotube.com/img/180x135/l/blank.png" class="flag flag-us" alt="United States of America" />
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
                <label for="pt-br">
                    <input name="culture" id="pt-br" value="pt-br" type="radio" @selected("pt-br", culture) /> Portugues <img src="http://st.xptotube.com/img/180x135/l/blank.png" class="flag flag-br" alt="Brasil" />
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>

    </fieldset>
}



@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function ($) {
            $("input[type = 'radio']").click(function () {
                $(this).parents("form").submit(); // post form
            });

        })(jQuery);
    </script>
}
```

Estou chamando ele assim no _Layout:

```
@Html.Partial("_Language")
```

Comment: A *Action* `SetCulture` de `HomeController` chega a ser chamada?

Comment: Não chega a ser chamada não.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Partials* não suportam `@section Scripts`. O correto seria esse código ficar em `_Layout` ou em alguma *View*, mas ele teria que ser modificado. Não o deixe na *Partial*.

Minha sugestão para `_Layout`:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function ($) {
            $("input[type='radio'][name='culture']").click(function () {
                $(this).parents("form").submit(); // post form
            });

        })(jQuery);
    </script>
```

Comment: Coloquei esse seu código como a última coisa antes de fechar o body, tirei o meu da partil, mas não funcionou, a impressão que dá é que ele não executa o script...

Comment: Pois é. Pode ser aquele `parents` ali.

Comment: Eu não sou conhecedor de javascript, ele funciona dentro de uma view normal. Eu tentei com documento.getbyid("form") colocando o um id no formulario, mas não pegou tb, acho estranho não conseguir colocar um form no Layout, como faria para ter uma função dessas funcionando tem todas as paginas?

Comment: Eu não vi q vc tirou o @section Scripts  do codigo, sem ele funcionou. Obrigado!